# Returning a string from a function c++

Tags: c++, string, function

Basicaly , i want to write a program that uses a function to display on the screen asterisks.The length is specified by the input parameter.so if the user inputs 2 it will look like this :

**

**

```
string myfunct(int thelength)
{
    string s1;
    for (int i=1;i<=thelength;i++)
    {
        string s1 =+ " * ";
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you didn't asked your question, but my guess is that you should use `+=` instead of `=+`.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use any of that but `return std::string(thelength, '*');` If you insist on using a loop, get used to starting at "index" zero and use `++i` instead of `i++` (for `int`s it doesn't matter what you use but for iterators it is often more efficient to use preincrement than postincrement).

Comment: You should probably also get a compiler that warns that your second `s1` hides your other `s1` variable.

Comment: So now you want what? n*2 asterisks, on separate lines?

Answer (score 4):

**Answering the original question**, which asked for a function that would return a string with `n` asterisks, where `n` is input by the caller.

`std::string` has a constructor that constructs a string with N copies of a given character:

```
std::string myfunct(int thelength)
{
  return std::string(theLength, '*');
}
```

This will return a string consisting of `theLength` asterisks `*`.

Comment: Who gave -1 ? +1 to compensate.

Comment: @Mahesh I did, for example. The provided solution does not match the requirements: It doesn't have a space to the left and right.

Comment: @IInspectable there was no such requirement.

Comment: @juan If you read the original code you would come to the same conclusion.

Comment: @IInspectable the point was to provide code that does what OP expressed they wanted, not to copy the errors in their code. I checked the string they wanted to create for input 2 and it was two asterisks without any spaces.

Comment: @IInspectable: the "spec" doesn't match the original code: I don't see any sign of spaces in the "spec" (if the gibberish written is to be consider that).

Comment: The OP clearly asked for `2` to return `"**"` so anyone adding spaces failed to read.

Comment: @JonathanWakely it seems the question has been changed...

Comment: @juan If you followed along with what you assumed to be the spec then you would have to return a string consisting of n lines with n asterisks each, separated by a blank line. How does your solution address this?

Comment: @IInspectable the question was changed. Originally it asked for `**` for `n=2`. Currently, it makes no sense.

Comment: At this point I think the asker is a troll and is trying to create pointless argument like this.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are all doing it wrong, you want:

```
std::string asterisks(int n) { return std::string(n, '*'); }
```

Comment: Except for my answer :) Which also got down-voted BTW.

Comment: "wrong" isn't accurate.  Suboptimally, yes, but also teaching the OP about loops and scopes.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, I think we answered at the same time - no idea why yours was downvited, I upvoted it

Comment: @BenVoigt, not wrong, but _doing it wrong_. As in http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/john-mccarthy-programming-wrong.jpg

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No, they aren't doing it wrong.  Assuming a different set of constraints than you are, perhaps.

Comment: Humour. You're [doing it wrong](http://memebase.cheezburger.com/verydemotivational/tag/doing-it-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define a local variable `string s1` inside for loop that overshadows the one defined outside. As a result in each iteration you add one asterix to an empty `s1` string. Moreover, replace =+ with +=. If the desired output is:

for size = 2

```
**

**
```

for size = 3

```
***

***
```

then your code may be like that:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string myfunct(int thelength)
{
    string s1; 
    for (int i=1;i<=thelength;i++)
    {   
        s1 += " * ";
    }   
    return s1; 
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter no of stars: ";
    int size;
    cin >> size;        

    cout << myfunct(size) << endl; 
    cout << endl; 
    cout << myfunct(size) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: in this code there will be no line-break

Comment: dev++ was giving me a permission denied sorry guys

Comment: @me.deeiip, right, the question has changed